# Linuxでターミナルを開き、自動でコマンドを入力できるようにしたい

Tags: python, linux

CentOSで複数個のターミナルを開き、各ターミナルごとに異なるコマンドを実行したいのです。

単純に並列でコマンドを実行した場合、一つのターミナルに一気に表示され、何が何だか理解できません。
そこで、ターミナルを別々に起動させ、各ターミナルごとに異なるコマンドを実行させることで、このグチャグチャになる事柄の解決方法は理解できたのですが、どうすれば実現できるのかが分かりません。

現状、手動で複数のターミナルを稼働させて実行していますが、面倒で仕方がありません。

プログラミング言語は、PythonかBashでお願いしたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: それぞれのコマンドがターミナルに結果を出力していて、同時に実行すると分からなくなってしまう…という事であれば、ターミナル (標準出力) に表示する代わりにコマンドごとに適当なログファイルに出力して結果を確認する、という方法も考えられますが、ここで求めているのはあくまで「自動でコマンドを入力」なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

デスクトップ環境は何ですか？
Gnomeなら下記のページが参考になると思います。

[新しい「GNOME端末」を開いてコマンドを実行する方法 | LFI](https://linuxfan.info/gnome-terminal-with-command)

違うデスクトップ環境でも同様のやり方はあると思いますのでターミナルコマンドのパスとオプションを確認してみては。

Comment: ありがとうございます。お陰様で解決しました。